# applicationId for Spark application on Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

When use spark-submit is it possible to get an applicationId ? The purpose is to stop the service when rest call is make by the client .

I found some info here regarding use applicationId here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

But I couldn't find any info about how get this applicationId

Comment: you can set and applicationId with the SparkConf definition.

Comment: have you tried to set it like spark-submit --conf spark.app.id=your_desired_id?